# export graph prototxt from tensorflow summary

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using tensorflow, the graph is logged in the summary file, which I "abuse" to keep track of the architecture modifications.
But that means every time I need to use tensorboard to visualise and view the graph.

Is there a way to write out such a graph prototxt in code or export this prototxt from summary file from tensorboard?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The graph is available by calling `tf.get_default_graph`. You can get it in `GraphDef` format by doing `graph.as_graph_def()`.